# QueueUserWorkItem not allowing Response to go back

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asynchronous

I'm writing an ASP.NET 3.5 web app and I want to "fire-and-forget" a task from Web.

Idea as follows:

- The user enters a Web page with a table, selects some items and submits the data with a button.
- The button, when pressed, fires an AJAX request back with the data.
- THe ASP.NET app starts a (background?) process. If the process is successfully started, the app will answer back to the client via AJAX.
- The process creates a text file with the data, saves it to a directory, and fires an SSIS package (the package mails the user once the process is complete) so no need for callbacks.

My problem is, when I use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem() to fire the process, my Web interface never receives the AJAX answer. The browser doesn't freeze, it just sits there, waiting.

Code:

The AJAX call

```
$("#btn-actualizar-instrumentos").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var contador = 0;
    $.each(state, function(i, val) {
        contador += val.length;
    });
    if (contador == 0) {
        alert("No se han seleccionado instrumentos para actualizar.");
        return;
    }
    else {
        $("#btn-actualizar-instrumentos").button("option", "disabled", true)
        $.blockUI({ message: "Enviando instrumentos seleccionados..." });
        var textoFinal = JSON.stringify(state);
        var idsFinal = JSON.stringify(ids);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'SDI_obtenerarchivosbloomberg.aspx',
            //data: textoFinal,
            data: idsFinal,
            success: function(response) {
                $("#div-resultados").html(response.mensaje);
                $("#div-resultados").dialog({
                    draggable: false
                });
                if (!response.oK) {
                    $("#btn-actualizar-instrumentos").button("option", "disabled", false); 
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, msg, msg2) {
                $("#div-resultados").html(xhr);
                $("#btn-actualizar-instrumentos").button("option", "disabled", false);
            },
            complete: function(e) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $.unblockUI();
                }, 0);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The ASP.NET code:

```
public partial class PageClass1 : System.Web.UI.Page

{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var instrumentos = new List<decimal>();

        // File generation and other tasks...

        // Invocation of fire-and-forget task

        var taskQueuing = ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(c => DoWork(instrumentos));

        // Building response

        mensaje += "<p>\n";
        if (taskQueuing)
        {
            mensaje += "Instrumentos procesados.<br />\n";
            mensaje += "Se le notificará por correo electrónico cuando la operación de actualización esté completa.<br />\n";
            mensaje += "Puede cerrar esta ventana ahora.<br />\n";
        }
        else
        {
            mensaje += "Error al enviar instrumentos:\n";
        }
        mensaje += "</p>\n";
        // JSONing response
        Response.StatusCode = 200;
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        Response.Write(textoRespuesta);
        Response.Close();
    }

    private void DoWork(List<decimal> lista)
    {
        // Invoking SSIS package
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As an aside isnt it a little heavyweight AJAXing off to an ASPX page, maybe a WebAPI endpoint might be more beneficial/more fit for purpose, anyhow  I have a feeling you'd have to mark the page as asynchronous in some way, as Im not sure how the scope of the page would be handled at the end of the page lifecycle.

Comment: Check this link out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx perhaps.

Comment: THanks for the tip. With that and some Fiddler, I found that the response correctly goes back so there must be a problem with JQuery (client-side).